# OpenCart 3 add a hidden option

Tags: filter, opencart

I have an OpenCart store where each product has multiple sizes, they also have different colors but each color is a different product.

Now I want to be able to filter the products by size and color too using Brainy Filter.

However that would mean that I have to add Color option to products. The problem is that this color option will have only one item (white for example, or blue, or green, etc.), so it is not necessary to show this option to the customer *[see image]*.

I'm guessing that I can count how many items an option has and if it's less than 2, then apply a class to hide the it, however the option is still visible in cart/checkout/order history and other pages.

My question is - is there any better way to do color filtering than to create a Color option (not using Tags)? If not, is there a clever way (except hiding it with CSS on every page that it's visible) to hide this option from the customer since they don't really need to see it.

[image]

Comment: If they can't choose it, so it's not an option. you can use attributes.

Comment: Like Arthur said use attributes they can be set to be filtered by BrainyFilter